Hyperion Interactive Reporting Studio Pivot Labels
We are using Hyperion Brio Query for reporting and I am trying to add column labels in the pivot table after running the report.  I cannot determine how to do this.
I am attaching a pic of what I want on an existing qry that HAS labels.  I cannot figure out how to add these on other query pivots.
Thank you - Rich
